# Simple example: HBase + Spring

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hbase

I find a simple example: HBase+Spring. I read some docs and articles about hbase configuration. I configured HBase server and now i want to create the client. I know what spring provides HbaseTemplate for working with Hbase. Maybe someone has an full example ? I need simple actions like put, get, delete.I would be glad to any working example.
Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: ок. I created some example https://github.com/dmgcodevil/HBaseDemo but when I start the test (testPut()) table not created, I think  what needed configure hbase-configuration, do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the spring-hadoop samples in github, specially the files in spring-hadoop-samples/original-samples/hbase-crud. The repository is at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hadoop-samples

Hope this helps you.
Good luck!